# Select of indices with wrong names in TypeORM

Tags: mysql, typescript, types, typeorm

When I try to select a Person with `.find()` it does a select as it should. But the select has several fields in it i did not declare like like this. Example:
Field:

```ts
... 
@Index("mail_blog_yn",["mail_blog_yn",])
...
export class person {
 ...
   @ManyToOne(type=>lov_jn_kz, mail_blog_yn=>mail_blog_yn.persons4)
   @JoinColumn()
   mail_blog_yn:lov_jn_kz;
 ...
}
```

Info: The Entity was generated with [TypeOrm-Model-Generator](https://github.com/Kononnable/typeorm-model-generator)

The select looks like this in the log:

```sql
...
`person`.`mailBlogYnKeyTypKz` AS `person_mailBlogYnKeyTypKz`
...
```

Here the code and the Connection setup:

```ts
typeorm.createConnection({
  type: "mysql",
  host: "localhost",
  port: 3306,
  username: Configuration.Database.user,
  password: Configuration.Database.password,
  database: Configuration.Database.database,
  entities: [
   ...
    person,
   ....
  ],
  synchronize: false,
  logging: true
}).then(connection => {
  const modelRepository: typeorm.Repository<person> =     connection.getRepository(person);
  modelRepository.find({
    "username" : 'x'
 }).then(( persons: person[]) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(persons));


  });
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Here is the `Person.ts` and the complete SQL statement and some data about my table person.
[Select-Problem.zip](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/files/1510672/Select-Problem.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its a Issue of the generator. (See here: [Typeorm Issue 1253](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1253) )

```
@ManyToOne(type=>lov_jn_kz, mail_blog_yn=>mail_blog_yn.persons4)
@JoinColumn()
mail_blog_yn:lov_jn_kz;
```

should be:

```
@ManyToOne(type=>lov_jn_kz, mail_blog_yn=>mail_blog_yn.persons4)
@JoinColumn({ name: "mail_blog_yn" })
mail_blog_yn:lov_jn_kz;
```

This fixes the issue but doing by hand is not an option for me, so typeorm-model-generator should definitely fix this.

Keep track of this issue on typeorm-model-generator: [Issue #13](https://github.com/Kononnable/typeorm-model-generator/issues/13)

Answer (score 0):

I have a **Workaround** for now:

Using the [QueryBuilder](http://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder) from TypeORM allows me to only select the values i really need and prevents the orm from selecting all values.

*Still waiting for a real solution.*